# regular expression to analyze site link

Tags: regex

I tried to create a regex string to analyze link

```
site- www.example.com/page.php?u=userid&action=add&date=yyyy-MM-dd
```

I want to create named groups as:

```
site: includes the full requested link     
user: includes value of u parameter    
action: includes value of action parameter
```

by taking example above the result will be:

```
site: www.example.com/page.php?u=userid&action=add&date=yyyy-MM-dd    
user: userid    
action: add
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

This regex gives you named captures of site, user and action,

```
(?=(?<site>www.*$))(?=.*u=(?<user>(?:[^&]*)))(?=.*action=(?<action>(?:[^&]*)))
```

Play here,

https://regex101.com/r/1VAgSO/1

Comment: @James: If this answer is working fine for you, can you please upvote and accept the answer? This will help others in case they have a similar question and they come here looking for an answer, they can easily follow this answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3

```
In[2]: from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
In[3]: url = 'www.example.com/page.php?u=userid&action=add&date=yyyy-MM-dd'
In[4]: parsed_url = urlparse(url)
In[5]: parsed_url
Out[5]: ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.example.com/page.php', params='', query='u=userid&action=add&date=yyyy-MM-dd', fragment='')
In[6]: parsed_query = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
In[7]: parsed_query
Out[7]: {'u': ['userid'], 'action': ['add'], 'date': ['yyyy-MM-dd']}
In[8]: {'site': url, 'user': parsed_query['u'], 'action': parsed_query['action']}
Out[8]: 
{'site': 'www.example.com/page.php?u=userid&action=add&date=yyyy-MM-dd',
 'user': ['userid'],
 'action': ['add']}
```

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs